# How to retrieve the history of changes happened to a particular Id in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table

```
select * 
from fServiceDetail  
where id = 111
```

For `Id = 111` in table `fServiceDetail` I want to see all past changes that happened across all  columns till now as a list.

How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: do you have a table where you save the field changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this if you do not have a historical or archive table that store this data.

**OR**

You have to use a third-party log reader (if log is not shrinked) like [ApexSQL LOG](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)